# Android Text Color can't be change

Tags: android

I have this following code. When i send a data on the list view I see nothing because the color was set to white. How can I set the color to black? there is no textColor property on it. Also How do I remove the gray color on each list item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f8f8f8"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/output_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use a custom adapter and change the text background

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a layout for the listview's rows and here you can set the color of the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/default_listview_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
```

Then you use it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.row_default, strings);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```